# Key hash for Facebook login in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash, facebook-login

Hi I am developing two android app with Facebook Login  features.I am getting the key hash by using this following code given by in Facebook doc

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.mypackage.xyzproject", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

I am getting the key hash like `2R9ySOpkkkqSwQW9JuO97YV2mnk=` for both the android app.So i am confused whether i will put the same key hash for both the app in Facebook developer account or i am getting the wrong key hash.

My next question is, may i have to generate different key hash for release in play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this for generation key hash :

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

**NOTE:** You have to install openssl 
I hope this will help you
Thank you.

### EDIT:

If you want to use your keystore then use following : 
`keytool -exportcert -alias "<your app's alias>" -keystore "Path of Keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

Try this.

Comment: It is asking for password may i have to enter the password which i had given during the apk signing.

Comment: ok. but i am getting the key hash  like this "HMiB7sOpF9Z4YoCbIwpIi5/p" how to know it is the right keyhash

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to generate 2 key hashes, because you do not sign in with debug.keystore. for the development purpose you need to generate a key hash from your debug.keystore, and to upload it to Google Play you need to generate a keyhash from your release.keystore. then put both hashes in FB app settings